# iOS Instagram profile View and scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, instagram

How did Instagram developers make profile view with switch between UICollectionView and UITableView?

I got two solutions:

1. **UIScrollView** which contains **UIView** at the top, and **UIView** which holds 
   **UICollectionView** and **UITableView** and delegates itself scrolling to these views?
2. Or **UITableView** and **UICollectionView** with **Top Insests** at each view?

Which one is better, what do you think?
May you provide other solutions?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like a **UICollectionView** with a custom header view to me.

Comment: And what about UITableView with big photos inside this controller?

Comment: Now that you changed the wording I see what you're asking. Yes it's both a collection view and a table view. They probably use the same header view within both and just hide/show the other when the user toggles between display modes.

Comment: I put my 5 cents on this: https://github.com/zwaldowski/AAPLAdvancedCollectionView

Comment: @user623396 too complex, it can be much easier.